# Random Access of Large Media Files on a Remote Web Server

Tags: web-services, video-streaming, media, random-access

One of our applications currently relies on mapped drives to access large media files (20-100MB) on the local network.

We would like to change this to some sort of web service so that we can make it more secure and move it to a web server (not relying on a local network).

Because they are large media files, we need to be have random access to the files (so that we can start videos from any point).

We have many different types of media files (MPEG, WMV, MOV, AVI, etc...) and would rather not encode them to a specific format for this purpose. We would much rather favor a technology that would allow us to access the file, as if it were a local file.

What technology should we use?

Answer (score 2):

HTTP already supports this natively.  However, your clients need to know how to support it.  It is the Content-Range header to specify the range to be requested and Content-Length to know the size.

If you need it as a "service" you can use WebDAV as well which provides semantics that would allow you to access a file system.  There's a WebDAV Servlet implementation as well which you can use as a starting basis.

Answer (score 1):

probably you just need [HTTP progressive download](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_download). You listed media containers that can contain almost arbitrary stream formats. In any case you can try to use [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) or another universal player that supports progressive download, most probably they can play your files.

Answer (score -2):

Use **Java**.

For securing the access - expose your authentication / authorization logic for the file store in any web service stack. for example axis , metro.

Java does have RandomAccessFile which can peek and seek to any point, but am not sure you really require this.

You existing application will have to have build some consumption mechanism for this.

Comment: wondering why it got down voted ? on question "We would much rather favor a technology that would allow us to access the file, as if it were a local file." - Have a look at Apache VFS

Comment: You suggested Java... any language can do random access on files... the problem is the protocol delivering it over the web.

Comment: Hmmmm..... The way I look at it... I didn't suggested here Java as Language ...I suggested Java as technology...A technology rich enough to support different protocols and problems using its libraries and versatile open source solutions... -:)...